# Getting "The file does not exist." when downloading files using JSch SFTP

Tags: java, windows, jsch

I am trying to fetch a file from Linux/Windows to a windows system, and I have written a code for this. But it seems there is some problem, either with the code or Jsch itself.

```
String host = "<IP>";

int port = Integer.parseInt("22");
String userName = "<USERNAME>";
String password = "<PASSWORD>";
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;
try {
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, port);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.connect();

  // open an SFTP channel
  Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
  channel.connect();
  sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

  File headerFolder = new File("/home/userName/testFiles");

  if (!headerFolder.exists()) {
    headerFolder.mkdirs();
  }

  sftpChannel.get("/d/myfile.txt", "/home/username/aFolder"); //windows to linux
} catch (JSchException e) {
  //LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SftpException e) {
  //LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2: The file does not exist.

```
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:913)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:873)​
```

Comment: "But it seems there is some problem, either with the code or Jsch itself" This is pretty vague. Could you explain exactly what problem you're having and where in the posted code the problem is  occurring? I can't relate those lines at the end of the question to anything in your code.

Comment: Error : sftpChannel.get("/d/myfile.txt","/home/username/aFolder");
The path expected for windows is not clear as in what is required (whether it should be in linux format or windws format).

Answer (score 1):

```
sftpChannel.get("/d/myfile.txt","/home/username/aFolder");
2: The file does not exist.
```

Your client tried to get "/d/myfile.txt", from the SFTP server, and the server responded that the file doesn't exist. You indicate the remote server is a Windows system, so I presume you're trying to get "D:\myfile.txt". It seems there are three possibilities here:

1. The file actually doesn't exist.
2. The file does exist, but you're not using the right SFTP pathname to get it.
3. The file does exist, but you're blocked from accessing it.

The SFTP protocol uses a unix-like model for file pathnames, so one would expect to use "/" as a separator and for absolute filenames to start with "/". If "/d/myfile.txt" isn't the right path to get the file, you should check the documentation for the SFTP server and/or ask the server administrator how to access the root of the D: drive through SFTP.

Alternately, you could try logging into the server with an interactive SFTP client and seeing what files are visible. If you were to cd to the / directory and start looking around, the correct path to the remote file may become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform change directory before listing out the files. I doesn't make sense but it worked for me.

```
 sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
 sftpChannel.cd(folder/subfolder);
```